# Android unit test, super deprecated, replacement?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

The android unit testing documents say to test with junit like this

```
public SpinnerActivityTest() {
      super("com.android.example.spinner", SpinnerActivity.class);
} // end of SpinnerActivityTest constructor definition
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html#InstallCompletedTestApp

Their example uses Android 2.1 though.

My app is using Android 4.2 although is backwards compatible.

What has the super class been replaced with? How should my constructor be written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API level 24 recommendations are to use the [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html).  The [`InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) method is probably what you want if you were using `getContext()`.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the call:

```
super (SpinnerActivity.class);
```

It's specified in the Android reference docs.

```
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(String pkg, Class<T> activityClass)
This constructor was deprecated in API level 8. use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(Class) instead
```

Use this instead.

```
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(Class<T> activityClass)
Creates an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Parameters
activityClass   The activity to test. This must be a class in the instrumentation targetPackage specified in the AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: both deprecated now.

Comment: What's the replacement for ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 now?